# Graph logistic regression with categorical predictors

Tags: regression, logistic, data-visualization, spss, multilevel-analysis

I am running a multilevel analysis for binary outcomes (i.e., similar to **binary logistic regression**), trying to predict use of negations based on **two categorical predictors** (patient type (MUS vs. MES), message content (positive vs. negative)) and two confounders (GP gender (m vs. f) and Patient gender (m vs. f)) on SPSS.

I found a significant interaction between patient type and message content, which I would like to plot. Based on the predicted probabilities, I created the following graph (in Excel, mean values derived from SPSS).

[image]

This data visualization, however, would be inappropriate since there is no linear relationship, but they are based on exponential functions. How do plot a graph that looks, for instance, like the following (content unrelated to my study):

[image]

Comment: I think the bottom graph is for a continuous predictor.

Comment: This would then mean that the visualization won't be possible for my data?

Comment: If you have categorical predictors, then it is not appropriate.